# Jquery promise chaining in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, method-chaining

I've got 2 functions returning promises that I would like to chain within a `foreach` loop. What's happening is that the first function is executed until the `foreach` is done before doing the second function for the array.

What I would expect is that for each `link`, `getLandingPageName` is executed then pass the new value coming from it to a form that I pass to `createLandingPage`.

```js
$('#btn_multi_lp').on('click', () => {
  let links = (findLpURL(HTML)) ? findLpURL(HTML) : getHrefLink(HTML);

  if (links) {
    let linksByNbr = countOccurrences(links);

    Object.keys(linksByNbr).forEach((link) => {
      let formLp = new FormData();
      formLp.append('campaign_id', $('#campaign_id').val())
      formLp.append('crea_id', 80);

      getLandingPageName($campaignName).then((dataLp) => {
        formLp.append('lp_name', dataLp.name);
        formLp.append('validated_lp', link);

        createLandingPage(formLp).then(() => {
          formLp.delete('validated_lp');
          formLp.delete('lp_name');
        }).catch((err) => {
          alert(err);
        })
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    });
  }
});


function getLandingPageName(campaignName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{{ route('account-creative-getlandingpagename') }}",
      data: {
        campaignName: campaignName,
        _method: 'POST' //we need this so we can send string data to server
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: (data) => {
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, error) => {
        reject('\nstatus code ' + jqXHR.status + '\n details: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  });

function createLandingPage(formData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{{ route('account-lp-create') }}",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: (data) => {
        /* data {success, response_lp, lp_paired_name } */
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, error) => {
        reject('creativeInstall : \nstatus code ' + jqXHR.status + ' \ndetails: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: $.ajax is asynchronous and javascript is single-threaded.  So your `foreach` has to complete before any async callback can fire.  Each `success:` as a callback that only runs once the http request has completed.

Comment: so the solution is to go synchronous then ?

Comment: No, definitely not.   Reconsider what you're trying to do.   Make a *batch* request instead of per link(?).   Make a single request instead of two.   Make a single batch request.